# Copy Validation Rules from element to another jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validations and i want to clone rules from an element to another one. Is it possible?

```
var rule = $('[id=' + elementToCopy + ']').rules();

$(this).rules("add", rule);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting appears to work, at least for simple rules like `required`.  Make sure and use the [Id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (`$("#" + elementToCopy)`) when you want to retrieve an element by id.  Also, be aware of the restriction on the [`rules("add", rules)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) method:

> Requires that the parent form is
>   validated, that is,
>   $("form").validate() is called first.

Basically, make sure both `form1` and `form2` containing `element1` and `element2` have had `validate()` called on them before you start adding/retrieving rules.

I've created a simple example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/4ShxX/

**Edit:** It also looks like this works for custom rules:

```
$.validator.addMethod("onlycharacters", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(value);
}, "Only characters");

$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            onlycharacters: true
        }
    }
});
$("#form2").validate();

var rules = $("#name").rules();
$("#name2").rules("add", rules);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/4ShxX/1/

Comment: @Xhalent: The OP doesn't mention error messages anywhere in the post, but you're correct.

Answer (score 1):

The script below copies the rules and the messages, the code you have only does it for the rules. Note the query for the messages uses element name, not element id.

```
var rules = $('#elementtocopy').rules();
rules['messages'] = $('form').data('validator').settings["your element name, NOT id"];
$('#newelementid').rules("add", args);
```

Comment: look this solutios, is very similar and works good, thanks a lot  
rules['messages'] = $('form').data('validator').settings['messages'][element.attr('name')];
                                                              
$(this).rules("remove");
$(this).rules("add", rules);

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. But will more elegant if you do this task using jQuery clone function. That make a deep copy of the set of matched elements. http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Passing first parameter you can copy the element with ALL events and attributes.

Comment: Perhaps, but this could yield incorrect results if the OP doesn't want all associated event listeners along with the `validate` rules.